# Office365-REST-Python-Client copy between two sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, python

I am struggeling to copy a file from one sharepoint site to another. Lets say i want to copy from: https://test.sharepoint.com/Site1/A/
to : https://test.sharepoint.com/Site2/B/

i have not yet found a solution or helpfull thing online for my problem. Perhaps anyone here can point me in the right direction, or help me out.

I believe the copyto only works in the same site, but i want to copy the file to another site...

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an anwser to this, i found it:

```
def copy_between_sites(username, password, site_url, origin_url, destination_url):
    # copy a file from one location in sharepoint to another location, can be in a different site

    origin = str(site_url + origin_url).replace(' ', '%20')
    destination = str(site_url + destination_url).replace(' ', '%20')
    destination = destination.rstrip(destination[-1])
    auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)

    if auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):

        request = ClientContext(site_url, auth)
        options = RequestOptions("{0}/sites/<your site>/_api/site/CreateCopyJobs".format(site_url))
        options.method = HttpMethod.Post
        options.data = {
        "exportObjectUris": [
            origin
        ],
        "destinationUri": destination,
        "options": {
            "IgnoreVersionHistory": True,
            "IsMoveMode": False,
            "BypassSharedLock": True
                    }
        }
        options.headers = {
            "X-RequestDigest": str(getToken(username=username_shrpt, password=password_shrpt, site_url=origin))
        }
        data = request.execute_request_direct(options)
        output = json.loads(data.content)
    else:
        print(auth.get_last_error())
    return

def getToken(username, password, site_url):
    # get the digest value from the site, for write access

    contextinfo_api = site_url + "/_api/contextinfo"
    auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)

    if auth.acquire_token_for_user(username,password):

        request = ClientContext(site_url, auth)
        options = RequestOptions(contextinfo_api)
        options.method = HttpMethod.Post

        data = request.execute_request_direct(options)
        output = json.loads(data.content)

        digest_value = output['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']

    else:
        print(auth.get_last_error())

    return digest_value
```